# FBSDKApplicationDelegates doesnot have a member named "application"

Tags: ios, swift

> `![FBSDKApplicationDelegates` does not have a member named
>   "application".

How I can handle this error in Swift?

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance.application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot `()`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    //Even though the Facebook SDK can make this determinitaion on its own,
    //let's make sure that the facebook SDK only sees urls intended for it,
    //facebook has enough info already!

    let isFacebookURL = url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(FBSDKSettings.appID())") && url.host == "authorize"
    if isFacebookURL {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    return false
}
```

This will be more safe.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo (I guess) in Parse as your code is what they posted under Facebook Users (see: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users).

So I agree with Ashish (except that I would say 'Parse' made a mistake! :) ).

If you type 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate.s' xcode will give you 'sharedInstance()'